# Taxonomy of web pages for illustrating the reach of "open data"

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I would like to do two things:

First, I want to draw some kind of structure of the web (data) in order to divert discussions about loose term "big data" to specific data topics.

Second, within this structure, I want to highlight the subset which is is considered open data.

Does anyone know if there is anything like that (e.g. a taxonomy tree) already available? Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

E.g., one example structure of the web (data):

1. social media
   a) facebook
   b) twitter
   ...
2. government data
3. homepages
   a) individuals
   b) companies
4. E-Commerce sites
   a) Amazon
   b) EBay
   ...
5. Blogs
6. Weather data

...

Then parts of 2. government data, homepages and weather data could be available as open data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some links which are useful for my question that I came across after performing a Google search for "types of web sites" brought among other these results:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media